# Why are reputation requirements different depending on the site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I've noticed something on multiple different stack sites that confuses me. For some reason, the reputation requirements for certain privileges are different.

For example, you need 50 reputation be able to comment on Stack Overflow questions, but you only need 5 on Meta Stack Exchange.

Another example, you need 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow, 500 on Meta Stack Exchange, and 1000 on Math Stack Exchange for the same privilege; create tags.

Why is that?

Comment: At least for the commenting requirements, I can see SO being a much bigger target for spam, so the higher requirements might be to make it near impossible to create spam accounts. 5 rep on the other hand is really easy to get, and they may have decided to have a lower requirement to support discussion.